# Make a php array load faster

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I successfully edited the checkout page of the WooCommerce city field in order to be a dropdown field with a lot of cities in it around 13k values the problem is that on mobile and some low-end devices this field isn't performing well how I can make this array load faster is a DB call worth it in this situation, is there any way stop the dropdown and make the field only searchable is it worth splitting the array or loading  from a text file?

The code I made

```
<?php

// Add custom checkout select fields
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_checkout_select_fields');
function add_custom_checkout_select_fields($fields)
{
    $arr = array(); // very big array arround 13k values
    

    // Define HERE in the array, your desired cities
    $cities = $arr;

    // Format in the right way the options array of cities
    $options = array(
        '' => __('Choose City', 'woocommerce') . '&hellip;'
    );
    foreach ($cities as $city)
    {
        $options[$city] = $city;
    }

    // Adding 2 custom select fields
    $fields['billing']['billing_city2'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_city2'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'required' => true,
        'options' => $options,
        'autocomplete' => 'address-level2',
        'input_class' => array(
            'wc-enhanced-select',
        )
    );

    // Copying data from WooCommerce city fields
    $fields['billing']['billing_city2']['class'] = array_merge($fields['billing']['billing_city']['class'], array(
        'hidden'
    ));
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city2']['class'] = array_merge($fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['class'], array(
        'hidden'
    ));
    $fields['billing']['billing_city2']['label'] = $fields['billing']['billing_city']['label'];
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city2']['label'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['label'];
    $fields['billing']['billing_city2']['priority'] = $fields['billing']['billing_city']['priority'] + 5;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city2']['priority'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['priority'] + 5;

    wc_enqueue_js("
    jQuery( ':input.wc-enhanced-select' ).filter( ':not(.enhanced)' ).each( function() {
        var select2_args = { minimumResultsForSearch: 1 };
        jQuery( this ).select2( select2_args ).addClass( 'enhanced' );
    });");

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: If your issue is with the dropdown loading slowly on particular devices, it's a DOM rendering issue, which you can't do anything about to make it faster. You'd be better off having an input field that loads city suggestions after, say, the first 3 characters are in. Otherwise, lazy-load the select options after a narrowing criteria, like state, is selected. Who's going to bother scrolling through 13K cities anyway?

Comment: The issue is that on the mobile version for instance the browser totally freezes.
It's not about the loading speed it's not even loading the page correctly.
Also, the user isn't scrolling he can search by the built-in library of WordPress but the array simultaneously loads as a dropdown too.

Comment: To repeat and clarify, "database call", "splitting the array" and "loading from a text file" would make no difference if your end product is the rendering of 13K options. Have you inspected the DOM to see what all is actually being rendered?

Comment: By inspection I got back <li> elements for every array value

Comment: loading all 13k array is overkill. what happen when 1000 users trying to load the same 13k array? just lazy-load the array or send it in small chunk